# Getting range of months - Java

Tags: java, android, java-time

I want to implement a tab layout with a range of months. This range should contain the last and next 12 Months.

I know how to get the next 12 months but i stuck at how to get the last AND next 12 months. I could use the joda time library but i think this lib is too big for my small android application.

Can anybody help my by providing a small code snipped? Thanks!

Comment: Show the current code you have that gets the next 12 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a Calendar class instance to do it, with [Calendar#add(int field,
       int amount)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29) like:

```
//getting month names
DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols();
String[] months = dfs.getMonths();

//here is what you need
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c.getTime().toString());
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -12);
for (int i = -12; i <=12; i++){
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);
    System.out.println(months[c.get(Calendar.MONTH)]);
}
```

`DateFormatSymbols` is here used, to get the names of the months only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the calendar class to get the current month. Then u can subtract 1 to get the value of last month or add 1 to get next month.

Here is an example snippet.

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
    int lastMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

U could write a loop to calculate last and next 12 months this way.

Cheers :)